# How do I insert <a> tag using :after css property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<tr id="TR_Select_Color">
  <td valign="top">
    <span class="boldtext">Select Color :</span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <select id="ctl01_Select_Color" >
      <option value="Black">Black</option>
      <option value="Brown">Brown</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

In the above code, I want to insert an `<a>` tag after the `<select>` tag. If it is not possible with CSS, how can I do it with JavaScript and jQuery?

Comment: Where do you want to insert this tag?

Comment: i can't understand what you want to do..?

Comment: What tag do want to insert ? where do you want to insert the tag? A jsfiddle would be helpful.

Comment: In the above code, I want to insert an <a> tag after the <select> tag.

Comment: @PoojaDesai see my answer you have that three options to do that

Comment: The intent of CSS is **styling** (hint: it can be desactivated and blind people won't perceive it except `display: none` and `visibility: hidden` most of the time because they don't desactivate it CSS of the time). An `a` element is structural, and a very important part of the structure of your HTML code as it allows the user to go to another page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't insert a tag with css pseudoelements. With jQuery however it is trivial:

```
$(aElement).insertAfter(spanElement);
```

Where aElement is your new a element and spanElement is the element you want to insert it after. See http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `.insertAfter()`.

> **Description:** Insert every element in the set of matched elements after the target.

```
$('<a>').insertAfter('tr#TR_Select_Color select');
```

**OR**

You can do it using `.after()`.

> **Description:** Insert content, specified by the parameter, after each element in the set of matched elements.

```
$('tr#TR_Select_Color select').after('<a>');
```

**OR**

You can also do it using `.append()`.

> **Description:** Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element in the set of matched elements.

```
$('tr#TR_Select_Color select').append('<a>');
```

Comment: `.append()` is not an option here, as it would place the anchor inside the `<select>` tag...

Answer (score 1):

You can add on any event here like on click event of button

```
$("button").click(function(){
       $("<a href="yourlink">Hello world!</a>").insertAfter("select");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [after](http://api.jquery.com/after/):

```
$("#ctl01_Select_Color").after("<a href='example.com'>This is an anchor</a>");
```